# Google voice actions CALL_ACTION

Tags: google-voice-actions

Can Google voice actions be used to make calls using 3rd party VOIP apps? Siri supports this but the documentation on Google isn't clear if this is supported.

When I add the intent-filter ACTION_CALL with CALL_PHONE permission set in my app. I still don't get the option to start the call with my app.

Answer (score 0):

I think one should be able to do this.

1. *call using Skype*
2. *call using WhatsApp*
3. *call using Messenger*

Both commands will open the app/intended `Activity`.
Looking at the `AndroidManifest.xml` for Skype as an example, it does not look like they are doing anything else than what you are already trying.

I agree with you. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/) is not very clear about this.
This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737095/app-already-published-onto-google-play-but-unable-to-use-google-voice-actions) could indicate that the app needs to be available on Google Play before it works.